# Image loader cache issue

Tags: jquery, loader

I have a large image with "loader" displayed while the image loads in the background, then when its fully loaded the image fades in. This works well when you first load the page or if you empty the cache, however it the image is cached the `loader_cont` stays on screen and the image never fades in. I guess this is b/c the images has technically already loaded. Any ideas around this? Here is the jQuery I currently have:

```
map_image.on('load',function(){
    $(".loader_cont").hide()
    $(".onload_fadein").animate({"opacity":"1.0"}, 1000)
});
```

Comment: The `load` event is also triggered when loaded from catch. But you likely attach the listener after the load happened.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - could you let me know how to do that? Still learning